# Hide a parent directory from a URL, or allow links not to require that parent directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP based website that I would like to make a little more secure and more SEO friendly. My site has two folders `private` and `site`. All public facing pages, css, scripts, images are in the `site` folder. All my backend PHP code is in the `private` folder. Currently I am protecting any access to the private folder by using `Deny from all` in an `.htaccess` file that is located in the `private` folder. On my local server (currently using XAMPP) the project is located in my `htdocs` folder and has a project name we will say is `example_project`. Under the `site` folder I have a few other sub directories sorting out the CSS, JS, images, and a few main sub categories of the pages in my site. I am trying very hard to figure out how to make it so that **(A)** the URL will NOT need to include `site` in the URL to access anything located under it and **(B)** it will change any requests including `site` in the URL to be rewritten to exclude it from the path.

**(A) Example**
`example_project/subfolder/index.php` accesses `example_project/site/subfolder/`

**(B) Example**
`example_project/site/subfolder/index.php` redirects to `example_project/subfolder/`

I have an `.htaccess` file in nearly every directory. In my top level of my *project (note that this is not the server web root)* I have the following `.htaccess` file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|png|pdf|swf|txt|php)$">
    #Used to allow for content expiration
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

#Force site to require https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#Allow links not to have the .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#THIS IS WHAT I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH
RewriteRule ^$ site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^site /example_project/site/$1 [NC,L]
```

**EDIT**
Please note that I just also remembered to add a capture group, so the last line now reads as `RewriteRule !^site/([-/\w]+) /hb1/site/$1 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment out first 2 `http->https` and `.php` rules** and test with these rules

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ site/ [L]

RewriteRule ^(?!site/).* site/$0 [NC,L]
```